# VideoView not shown in xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Hello I have a problem with a videoview not shown in my XML layout while i run the application in my device. I am only pasting the xml as I am sure that the java class is correct, I just can't figure this out, so if anyone available please help me

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ballbackground"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.buttondemo.FootballBalls" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/btnRules" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/worldcupball"
            android:layout_width="227dp"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:background="@drawable/worldcupball"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainActivityHeader"
            android:layout_width="228dp"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            android:text="@string/ball_explanation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ball_construction" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="138dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roteirotechdrawing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/OutfitView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: is it possible its going offscreen?

Comment: what is that exactly?how do I check that?

Comment: Why don't you use Design/preview view in Android Studio? You will see exactly how your layout looks like, and should be able to spot any issues as above...

Comment: I am using Eclipse. is that possible to do so in Eclipse?

Comment: @cmario It should be.  Eclipse isn't as reliable on the UI front, but the page where you typed the XML layout information in should have a tab at the bottom labelled 'Graphical Layout'.  After clicking on that you can get a rough idea most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to hard define your layouts.  If you want them to take up specific areas of space on the screen, then you should look into layout weights. Or use wrap_content for TextView heights.  But in some circumstances within a ScrollView you can get away with it.

Does it not scroll?

It is also possible that your VideoView won't load or show until you put content inside of it.  This is because you have a wrap_content for it's height.  It won't have a height until then.  That could be what you are experiencing right now.